# Mac OSX : python packages failed to build because of gcc issues

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

I am trying to install `MySQL-python` package with the following error:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using `Mac OSX version 10.6.8` with gcc

```
bash-3.2$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

How can I resolve the this issue?

thanks

Comment: What version of Python?  `-arch` might mean mysql-python is trying to compile into i386 or x86_64, and whichever one it is, your Python doesn't like it.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with Python directly.  The error is coming from `gcc`.  `-arch` is an Apple extension to `gcc` found only in the Apple-supplied `gcc`'s shipped in Xcode.

Comment: This issue has been resolved, I have added my answer to this. Thanks Ned and Cody

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I restored the `gcc` that comes with Mac and that removed the first error which is

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
```

for the second one, I removed the option from   `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.5/config/Makefile`
from `BASECFLAGS` and added the following to my ~/.bashrc

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib
```

and that removed the error

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Apple-supplied `gcc` that comes with the Xcode Developer Tools.  There should be a Snow Leopard version of Xcode that either came with your Mac or is on a system restore DVD or a retail copy of Snow Leopard or can be downloaded (after free registration) from the Apple Developer Connection.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1：**

May be missing installation package of pyton-dev：

```
$  yum list | grep python-dev
$ yum -y install python-dev*     //need root privileges
```

After the execution, re-installation.

**Solution 2：**

If solution 1 does not resolve the problem, might be "gcc" is not installed or are no longer in the PATH

```
$ whereis gcc         //check gcc
$ echo $PATH        //Check the gcc whether in the PATH
```

If you do not install the "gcc", execute the following command

```
$ yum list | grep gcc
$ sudo yum install -y gcc.x86_64
```

After the execution, re-install.