# MySQL "unrecognized command line option '-aes'" with ruby 1.9.3-p125?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I have just recently installed ruby 1.9.3-p125 on Mac OS X.  I use rvm for ruby mgmt and homebrew for mysql, etc.

Oddly I've hit an odd issue with p125 that does not seem to happen at all on p0 and was hoping for some insight into what may be happening here:

```
$ gem install mysql2                                                                                                                                                            
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling result.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-aes"
make: *** [result.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@all/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@all/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Oddly if I uninstall mysql and reinstall it, then build the gem, it seems to work... but only after that extreme exertion each time.

Just to clarify, Xcode 4.3 is installed and the build environment appears to be entirely sane.  If I remove the `-aes` from the mysql2 Makefile it will build and install just fine, so for some reason this appears to be a combinatorial effect perhaps of ruby 1.9.3-p125, mysql2 and perhaps the new Xcode 4.3...

Comment: Interesting comment I just received from the `mysql2` developer: "I actually just had a co-worker hit the same exact error. No idea where the -aes option is even coming from. Definitely let me know if you track something down." [link to issue](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/245)

Comment: Now resolved. Original discussion of the issue: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10549#issuecomment-4208528
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using cc instead of gcc for compiling. Please ensure Xcode is installed . Read more here [Mac OSX : python packages failed to build because of gcc issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572429/mac-osx-python-packages-failed-to-build-because-of-gcc-issues)

Comment: Unfortunately it's all installed and the environment is sane.  The only issue issue I'm having is that with -aes in the `mysql2` `Makefile`, the gem does not build.  However, if it is present, `mysql2` does not build.