# Error because of gcc -arch

Tags: python, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, installation

The error is:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
```

which comes from my attempt to install GEOS by using:

```
python setup.py install
```

In full, the terminal output reads:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 97, in <module>
    objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
  File "/Users/ged/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 205, in CCompiler_compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/Users/ged/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 40, in UnixCCompiler__compile
    raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/ged/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Isrc -c nad2bin.c -o nad2bin.o" failed with exit status 1
```

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572429/mac-osx-python-packages-failed-to-build-because-of-gcc-issues) has been asked already, and the solution was to revert back to the `gcc` that originally came with the Mac (OS X ver. 10.7.3)

If that could be the solution I'm looking for, how do you restore `gcc`?

If you need additional information, please leave a comment.

Thanks!

Comment: If this question has already been asked and answered you should try the existing answers before posting your own new question. If it doesn't work, open a new question and explain where the existing solution went wrong for you. How to revert or "restore" GCC should be its own question. You will be more likely to get a good answer by focusing your question on that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OSX : python packages failed to build because of gcc issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572429/mac-osx-python-packages-failed-to-build-because-of-gcc-issues)